# php permission denied on executing a C exe file

Tags: php, apache, selinux

Im using Fedora 14 and tried to execute a C program inside a php script using the backtick operator.

It said `permission denied`, but it works for other bash commands, e.g. `test.sh`; it only contains `ls -lrt` .

Both `test.sh` and `a.out` have the permissions and both belongs to the apache users.

Note: It runs fine on the command line and I get permission denied when accessing from a browser.

Comment: Is it an `.exe` file in linux environment?

Comment: Let's see your code my good man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. I fixed it by disabling SELinux.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a new file context for your executable as well as a transition that allows httpd to execute files marked with this context.

Comment: how to create it , any example